# Sed not working right when executing shell script (.sh file) via a batch file using plink but works perfectly when executed manually using ssh (putty)

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, sed

I am having an issue getting sed to work correctly. I have a shell script (.sh file) on a remote server that is running Cent OS Linux. I want to execute using a batch file and Plink. When I execute the shell script (.sh file) using Putty or any other ssh ( e.g ./backup.sh ) it works fine but when I execute the shell script (.sh file) using a batch file sed throws an error message.

Here is how sed is being used in part of the shell script (.sh file) named backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%s)
sed -i -e '1i'$date'\' backup/backups.txt
```

Here is my batch file

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty
plink user@my.server.com -pw passwd /the/directory/backup.sh
```

Here is the error message sed is throwing

```
sed: can't read backup/backups.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I would put a `pwd` command at the top of your bash script and see what it says when you run it each way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are executing the script by hand as `./backup.sh` whereas via putty/ssh, it's run as `/the/directory/backup.sh`.  It's all fine, but it suggests they are not run in the same working directory, so `backup/backups.txt` is not referring the same place.

You can try changing to the correct directory as the first line in the script (via `cd`) or referring to the absolute, full pathname of the backups.txt instead.